# Conditional format alternate between 2 colours for groups of rows based on value change

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet that is in Google Sheets which has a column that I want to format conditionally. I want to format it, such that groups of rows which all hold the same value are dark grey, while they next group of rows of all the same value are light grey. For example, I want the sheet to look something like this:

[image: column]

The numbers will not neccesarily be grouped in order, so I can't just use `=mod(a1,2)=1` for the conditional format. I also would like it to update so that no matter how the other columns are filtered, this column remains such that every time the value in the next row is different, it and its duplicates are all a new color, mainly for visualization, to see which data is grouped together.

If I'm to use the formulae `=isodd(countunique(a$2:a2))` and `=isodd(countunique(a$2:a2))` and then apply some filter, then I get the following, which doesn't alternate the colors based on what is shown.

[image]

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
=isodd(countunique(a$1:a1))
```

for the light grey and

```
=iseven(countunique(a$1:a1))
```

for the dark grey

[image]

**EDIT**

The same question was asked in Excel recently and I realised it would be better just to count the changes of value like this:

```
=ISEVEN(SUMPRODUCT(--(A$1:A1<>A$2:A2)))
```

This does highlight correctly if a duplicate appears in more than one continuous sequence:

[image]

whereas the original formula would have highlighted incorrectly:

[image]

It doesn't solve the filtering question though.

Comment: I think that's what OP wants

Comment: @TomSharpe This is a good solution, thanks. The only problem is that when I filter it, the highlighting won't update. Is there any way to do that? I'll edit the original post to show what I mean.

Comment: I can't think of a way of adapting this to filtered cells using only a formula. If a script would be acceptable I could look into either finding the background colour of the previous cell or testing if it visible using some code.

Comment: I don't think the numbers necessarily go in sequence (OP says =mod(a1,2)=1 wouldn't work which is the same as isodd). The real challenge is doing it for filtered data - I can't think of a way to do it even with a script because there seems to be no way of testing if a cell is visible.

Comment: @TomSharpe If it requires a script, I can take care of it; I was only hoping to find something simpler but that's alright. Thanks for helping regardless

Comment: @teepee If this answer helped you, please note that you can [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @TomSharpe Thanks for this answer and especially the edit. I think it's worth mentioning that the "apply to range" for this custom formula should start at A2 (not A1) for it to work correctly. Otherwise the coloring is off by 1 row. Got me stumped for a couple of minutes.